# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, garbage-collection

I have read all the other questions related to this error and have tried their solution, but it doesn't help.

Here is my build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "zebrostudio.wallr100"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        //apply plugin: 'application'
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = true
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':library:altex')
    compile project(':library:ucrop')
    compile project(path: ':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:simple-item-decoration:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.3'
    apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.1.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'wallr100')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.2'
    compile 'fr.tvbarthel.blurdialogfragment:lib:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.3.6'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-cab:0.1.12'
    compile project(':lowpoly')
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile project(':librarySecuredPref')
    compile 'com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.5.1'
    compile project(':librarySearch')
    compile 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:WaveSwipeRefreshLayout:1.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried it on **Android Studio 2.1.3** and **Android Studio 2.2.3**
I have tried uninstalling jdk and then reinstalling it.
I have formatted my windows and retried, but to no avail.

[image: It creates so many background processes and the computer starts slowing down.]

I keep on getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error

How do I solve this?

Comment: First of all, it would probably help if you specified when you are getting this `OutOfMemoryError` - when starting Android Studio, when running your application in simulator, when running Gradle, or when what?  Secondly, OOME is about Java application running out of so called heap space, so simply speaking - some Java program ('which one' is covered by the first question) needs to use more memory than it's allocated. You better figure out what program that is.

Comment: Building the project works fine. The problem occurs when I am trying to deploy it to my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself. The problem was solved when i trimmed the number of dependencies that i was using. So for anyone facing this issue, just try to lessen the number of libraries you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A further solution is use gradle file. I overcame the error using by `gradle.properties` file. If there isn't in your project, you should create the file in `project level`. Gradle use 1024m memory by default. You can increase up to 1536m (I did 2048m because I have 16g memory). I don't take an error after do that.